# TableLayout width anomaly

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-view

I have a nested TableLayout (TableLayout->TableRow->TableLayout->TableRow). The inner TableLayouts have their width set to MATCH_PARENT. It is not expanding to match its parent. See attached screenshots.[image: Child TableLayout]
[image: Parent TableRow]

**EDIT:**

I can tweak the width using android:weight and setting the android:layout_width="0dp". I still want to understand this behaviour.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: No. I worked around it as mentioned in the edit.